# Efficient algorithm that takes a Twitter user and finds top users by order of how many of his followers they follow

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

The title is very wordy. So I'll explain with an example.

We have a database of 10,000 twitter users with each following up to 2000 users. The algorithm takes as input one random never before seen user (including the people that follow him), and returns the twitter users from the database by order of how many of his followers they follow.

i.e. 
We have:

User A follows 1,2,3,4

User B follows 3,4,5,6

User C follows 4,8,9

We enter user X who has users 3,4,5 following him.

The algorithm should return:

B: 3 matches (3,4,5)

A: 2 matches (3,4)

C: 1 match (4)

Comment: By database, do you mean SQL database?

Comment: Is this something that matters? I'm more concerned with the efficiency of the algorithm and how best to setup the data for quick comparisons. But the data is stored in a db, not memory if tgat's what you're inquiring about :)

Comment: What have you tried? It depends on the framework you are using. Basically, you can sum columns of selected rows of a sparse Boolean matrix. What will you do with the output? Maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: @DavidHaddad I ask because if it's already in a database, then the best solution is likely to be an SQL query.

Comment: Cyborg, what you mention sounds interesting, can you elaborate? It seems like the best solution for this would require some linear algebra/ matrix type of stuff which I'm not very good at conceptualizing. But that wouldn't be too hard to implement given the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table structure similar to this:

**Table Users**

```
Id (PK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
Username (nvarchar(50), not null)
```

**Table UserFollowers**

```
UserId (FK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
FollowerId (uniqueidentifier, not null)
```

You can use the following query to get the `common` parents of followers of the `followers of the user in query`

```
SELECT     Users_Inner.Username, COUNT(Users_Inner.Id) AS [Total Common Parents]
FROM         Users INNER JOIN
                  UserFollowers ON Users.Id = UserFollowers.FollowerId INNER JOIN
                  UserFollowers AS UserFollowers_Inner ON UserFollowers.FollowerId = UserFollowers_Inner.UserId INNER JOIN
                  Users AS Users_Inner ON UserFollowers_Inner.FollowerId = Users_Computed.Id
WHERE     (UserFollowers.UserId = 'BD34A1FF-FCF5-4D35-B8A3-EFFB1587A874')
GROUP BY Users_Inner.Username
ORDER BY COUNT(Users_Inner.Id) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the data as a sparse integer matrix `A` of size 10^5x10^5 with ones at the appropriate places. Then, given a user `i`, compute `A[i,] * A` (matrix multiplication). Then sort.

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work?

```
for f in followers(x)
    for ff in followers(f)
        count[ff]++  // assume it is initially 0

sort the ff-s by their counts
```

Unlike the matrix solution, the complexity of this is proportional to the number of people involved rather than the number of users on twitter.